# How did I end up with these unknown folders/files on my external drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, filesystems, temporary-files

Here is snapshot of my external drive. I never store any files directly in its root folder yet I have bunch of files eula.###.txt and others for example install.exe and similar files. How did they get there?

More important there are a number folders with numeric names. These are all zero bytes folders and has nothing inside them. What does this mean and how did it get there?

Note: I have masked my own files with boxes.

[image]

Comment: They are Windows Updates, which has a habit, of using the largest disk available to store the files. Which updates other than VC++ in the case of the folder you have provided, is more difficult to identify.  Folders can be deleted if you don’t care about removing the updates.

Comment: For reference: To find the root cause, check this answer of similar question: https://superuser.com/a/1367433/948071

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are leftover files from installations of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio. I had them too. You can safely delete them.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/950683/vcredist-from-vc-2008-installs-temporary-files-in-root-directory

Comment: You beat me to it, so +1. It doesn't explain the empty folders though, but from doing some quick Googling they are safe to delete.

Comment: Yes, apparently the empty folders are temporary folders for Windows Updates, with some saying they're the .NET Framework.